# Firefox Renders Elements Differently When TranslateY Applied

Tags: css, firefox, transform, translate

Applying a translateY on hover makes a link look like it moves to the side in Firefox (current version). It is caused by the margin-left applied with em and it is not really moving pixels but just rendering differently, which visually looks like moving. Chrome has no issues.

Here is a sample page:

```css
.icon-button-user-action-base {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

.icon-button-user-action-base:hover i {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<a href="#" class="icon-button-user-action-base" style="font-size: 83px;">
  <i class="far fa-square"></i>
</a>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 98px; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 100px; background-color: blue;">

</div>
```

[image: Example rendering with and without hover]

Any idea of how to fix this without changing the margin to px?

Comment: running your snippet with chrome and FF shows no difference , Is there all code needed to demonstrate the issue ?

Comment: Can't repro here either on macOs with a retina display, but it's very plausible indeed that by using `em` you actually fall on floating pixel coordinates (16.6px) and that forcing the GPU rendering by using `transform`, renders it differently than when there is no transform (e.g software rendering always rounding things, while GPU one using antialiasing instead). (FWIW on my machine I always have antialiasing on)

Comment: Open this page in Firefox, on my sample click on "Expand snippet" and then on "Run code snippet", then you will see it very clearly. Or just create a simple html page adding the styles and html code (unfortunately cut out by stackoverflow).

Comment: @Kaiido I test on the same machine with Firefox and Chrome, only FF has the issue. It seems to be the rendering mechanism by FF that causes the problem, not hardware antialiasing. Also movement should generally not change the way straight lines are rendered.

Comment: Without the transform, the browser may use software rendering on your machine (on mine it does use GPU all the time). This software rendering will round coords and thus look *sharper*. The GPU rendering on the other hand will not round the coords but generate anti-aliasing. When you add the *transform* rule, the browser will switch from software rendering to GPU rendering. That's why you have a line when the rule is active: the antialiasing will render the 0.4px gap using semi-transparent pixels. Note that on my machine I always see that gap. The  solution is to use integer coords (i.e px).

Comment: @Kaiido You say your machine uses GPU all the time. Can I force that so that I verify that this is the issue?

Comment: Depends on your hardware.